# How to make makefile exit with error when using a loop?

Tags: bash, makefile

If I have the following bash command:

```
for i in ./ x ; do ls $i ; done && echo OK
```

"ls ./" is executed, and then "ls x", which fails (x is missing) and OK is not printed.

If

```
for i in x ./ ; do ls $i ; done && echo OK
```

then even though "ls x" fails, because the last statement in the for loop succeeded, then OK is printed. This is a problem when using shell for loops in makefiles:

```
x:
    for i in $(LIST) ; do \
        cmd $$i  ;\
    done
```

How can I make make fail if any of the individual executions of cmd fails?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `break` command to terminate the loop when a command fails

```
x:
    for i in $(LIST) ; do \
        cmd $$i || break ;\
    done
```

That won't make the makefile abort, though. You could instead use `exit` with a non-zero code:

```
x:
    for i in $(LIST) ; do \
        cmd $$i || exit 1 ;\
    done
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Replacing cmd with ls and LIST=non_existing_file, then make continues on its merry way after "ls non_existing_file" fails.

Comment: Another option is to `set -e` prior to running the loop.

Comment: Calling `exit` doesn't terminate the makefile.  It spawns a shell, telling it to do nothing but `exit`.  `exit 1` causes the makefile rule to fail because it causes the shell to exit with an error code, indicating failure.

Comment: @DavidC. The shell was already spawned for the `for` command. `exit` doesn't spawn a new shell, it causes that shell to exit (which stops the loop as well). And giving it a non-zero code then causes `make` to terminate.

Comment: Oops.  I forgot about the `for` loop.  An `exit` call by itself would spawn a new shell.

Answer (score 1):

After executing the command, check for return value of that command using `$?`, as its make file you need to use double `$`. If its non zero, then exit with failure.

```
x:
    set -e
    for i in $(LIST); do \
        cmd $$i; \
        [[ $$? != 0 ]] && exit -1; \
        echo 'done'; \
    done
```

Comment: Unless you use `.ONESHELL` in GNU make, make will execute every line in its own shell, therefore the `set -e` will not affect the `for`-loop. You could however join the `set -e` with the loop with by escaping the newline and adding a semicolon.