# Make Exits Successfully with Errors In A Test

Tags: bash, makefile

This question isn't about how to resolve the aborted core dump or the error. I would like for my tests to fail, and then make fail.

I believe my actual issue is with this recipe.

```
tests: $(TSTE)
    for test in $^ ; do \
        chmod +x ./$${test} ; \
        ./$${test}; \
    done
```

I suspect because it is not exiting in the for loop. I would actually prefer if all tests ran first, and then summed the exit codes and exited. I'm not sure how to do that.

the output from make.

```
for test in target/utils.exe target/requester.exe target/responder.exe target/header.exe target/server.exe ; do \
        chmod +x ./${test} ; \
        ./${test}; \
done
success 
header.exe: tests/header.c:33: test_methods: Assertion `get == GET' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/christopher/source/caffeine'

Press ENTER or type command to continue

$ echo $?                               
0
```

I need make to exit with an error code so that my cicd pipeline can fail as well.

**edit**

This question isn't answered by this one. [How to make makefile exit with error when using a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436631/how-to-make-makefile-exit-with-error-when-using-a-loop)

As this one states to exit immediately, I would still like all tests to finish, and the aggregate exit code bubble up to make.

Comment: Put `|| exit` if you want the program to abort. When you run `cmd1; cmd2`, the exit status of the compound command is that of `cmd2`, not `cmd1`, unless `set -e` is used (and that [has its own problems](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)). In the above case, only the exit status of `target/server.exe` is passed from the shell back to `make`; the others don't impact the shell's exit status because they aren't the last command the shell runs.

Comment: That is to say, `./${test} || exit;`

Comment: I only want to exit after the loop has finished. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Then you'll need to store a variable to track whether any errors have been seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do it from within the shell script, just as you'd do it if you wrote a shell script.  Something like:

```
tests: $(TSTE)
        err=0; \
        for test in $^ ; do \
            chmod +x ./$${test} ; \
            ./$${test} || err=$$?; \
        done; \
        exit $$err
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. I didn't think about err being the exit code only if there was an error because of the `||`